# Inativar e Ativar um usuário com um botão

Tags: php

eu criei um botão no front end em java script onde é um botão e clicando aparece uma pop-up, com ok e cancel, eu quero e preciso que clicando em ok essa função inative um usuário, então preciso escrever essa função no back-end, porém já pesquisei e ja tentei de todas as formas, precisa trocar em outra página o status desse usuário de "a" (ativo) para "i" (inativo).

FUNÇÃO DO FRONT-END

```
function inativar_usuario() 
        {
            var resposta = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja inativar este usuario ?");

            if (resposta == true)
            {
                alert ("Usuario Inativado");
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'sat/rotinas/sat_gerencia_cadastro.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action: 'inativar_usuario'
                }
            })
        }
```

O BOTÃO

```
 <a class="glyphicon-action" style="background-color: #0b8904 !important;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Inativar usuário" onclick="return inativar_usuario()"><span class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu data{}, coloque um campo chamado resposta, ai no seu codigo php receba esse campo resposta, se ele for igual a true significa que o usuario deve ser inativado, sendo assim so dar um update no seu usuario.
Voltando para o js

```js
$.ajax({
        url: 'sat/rotinas/sat_gerencia_cadastro.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'inativar_usuario'
        }
    })
    .done(function(){
      console.log("feito")
    })
    .fail(function(response){
      console.log(response)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```